# Getting two different output from same json

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

[image][image] I have a D3 api which i have to show some relations  i use json for the data but for two different times i get two different output for the api from the same structure of json. i am posting the two jsons.

```
{
"nodes" : [ {
    "name" : "Jeet123",
    "type" : 1,
    "slug" : "",
    "entity" : "company"
}, {
    "name" : "9804500485",
    "type" : 2,
    "slug" : "",
    "entity" : "number"
}, {
    "name" : "9804086391",
    "type" : 2,
    "slug" : "",
    "entity" : "number"
}, {
    "name": "offnet",
    "type" : 3,
    "slug" : "",
    "entity" : "employee"
},{
    "name" : "onnet",
    "type" : 3,
    "slug" : "",
    "entity" : "employee"

},{
    "name" : "offsms",
    "type" : 4,
    "slug" : "",
    "entity" : "description"

},{
    "name" : "offvoice",
    "type" : 4,
    "slug" : "",
    "entity" : "description"

},{
    "name" : "onsms",
    "type" : 4,
    "slug" : "",
    "entity" : "description"

},{
    "name" : "onvoice",
    "type" : 4,
    "slug" : "",
    "entity" : "description"

}, {
    "name": "offnet1",
    "type" : 3,
    "slug" : "",
    "entity" : "employee"
},{
    "name" : "onnet1",
    "type" : 3,
    "slug" : "",
    "entity" : "employee"

},{
    "name" : "offsms1",
    "type" : 4,
    "slug" : "",
    "entity" : "description"

},{
    "name" : "offvoice1",
    "type" : 4,
    "slug" : "",
    "entity" : "description"

},{
    "name" : "onsms1",
    "type" : 4,
    "slug" : "",
    "entity" : "description"

},{
    "name" : "onvoice1",
    "type" : 4,
    "slug" : "",
    "entity" : "description"

},{
    "name" : "Subho",
    "type" : 1,
    "slug" : "",
    "entity" : "company"
}, {
    "name" : "9804125689",
    "type" : 2,
    "slug" : "",
    "entity" : "number"
}, {
    "name" : "9854789651",
    "type" : 2,
    "slug" : "",
    "entity" : "number"
}, {
    "name": "offnet",
    "type" : 3,
    "slug" : "",
    "entity" : "employee"
},{
    "name" : "onnet",
    "type" : 3,
    "slug" : "",
    "entity" : "employee"

},{
    "name" : "offsms",
    "type" : 4,
    "slug" : "",
    "entity" : "description"

},{
    "name" : "offvoice",
    "type" : 4,
    "slug" : "",
    "entity" : "description"

},{
    "name" : "onsms",
    "type" : 4,
    "slug" : "",
    "entity" : "description"

},{
    "name" : "onvoice",
    "type" : 4,
    "slug" : "",
    "entity" : "description"

}, {
    "name": "offnet1",
    "type" : 3,
    "slug" : "",
    "entity" : "employee"
},{
    "name" : "onnet1",
    "type" : 3,
    "slug" : "",
    "entity" : "employee"

},{
    "name" : "offsms1",
    "type" : 4,
    "slug" : "",
    "entity" : "description"

},{
    "name" : "offvoice1",
    "type" : 4,
    "slug" : "",
    "entity" : "description"

},{
    "name" : "onsms1",
    "type" : 4,
    "slug" : "",
    "entity" : "description"

},{
    "name" : "onvoice1",
    "type" : 4,
    "slug" : "",
    "entity" : "description"

}  
],

"links" : [ {
    "source" : 0,
    "target" : 1,
    "value" : 1,
    "distance" : 5
}, {
    "source" : 0,
    "target" : 2,
    "value" : 1,
    "distance" : 5
}, {
    "source" : 1,
    "target" : 3,
    "value" : 1,
    "distance" : 5
},{
    "source" : 1,
    "target" : 4,
    "value" : 1,
    "distance" : 5
},{
    "source" : 3,
    "target" : 5,
    "value" : 2,
    "distance" : 5
},{
    "source" : 3,
    "target" : 6,
    "value" : 1,
    "distance" : 5
},{
    "source" : 4,
    "target" : 7,
    "value" : 2,
    "distance" : 5
},{
    "source" : 4,
    "target" : 8,
    "value" : 1,
    "distance" : 5
},{
    "source" : 2,
    "target" : 9,
    "value" : 1,
    "distance" : 5
},{
    "source" : 2,
    "target" : 10,
    "value" : 1,
    "distance" : 5
},{
    "source" : 9,
    "target" : 11,
    "value" : 2,
    "distance" : 5
},{
    "source" : 9,
    "target" : 12,
    "value" : 1,
    "distance" : 5
},{
    "source" : 10,
    "target" : 13,
    "value" : 2,
    "distance" : 5
},{
    "source" : 10,
    "target" : 14,
    "value" : 1,
    "distance" : 5
},{
    "source" : 15,
    "target" : 16,
    "value" : 1,
    "distance" : 5
},{
    "source" : 15,
    "target" : 17,
    "value" : 1,
    "distance" : 5
},{
    "source" : 16,
    "target" : 18,
    "value" : 2,
    "distance" : 5
},{
    "source" : 16,
    "target" : 19,
    "value" : 1,
    "distance" : 5
},{
    "source" : 18,
    "target" : 20,
    "value" : 2,
    "distance" : 5
},{
    "source" : 18,
    "target" : 21,
    "value" : 1,
    "distance" : 5
},{
    "source" : 19,
    "target" : 22,
    "value" : 2,
    "distance" : 5
},{
    "source" : 19,
    "target" : 23,
    "value" : 1,
    "distance" : 5
},{
    "source" : 17,
    "target" : 24,
    "value" : 1,
    "distance" : 5
},{
    "source" : 17,
    "target" : 25,
    "value" : 1,
    "distance" : 5
},{
    "source" : 24,
    "target" : 26,
    "value" : 2,
    "distance" : 5
},{
    "source" : 24,
    "target" : 27,
    "value" : 1,
    "distance" : 5
},{
    "source" : 25,
    "target" : 28,
    "value" : 2,
    "distance" : 5
},{
    "source" : 25,
    "target" : 29,
    "value" : 1,
    "distance" : 5
    }
  ]
}
```

this is the json which is working fine

and this is the json which is not working correctly .

```
 {
"nodes":[{
    "name":"9748108991",
    "type":1,
    "slug":"",
    "entity":"company"
},{
    "name":"offnet",
    "type":1,
    "slug":"",
    "entity":"employee"
},{
    "name":"onnet",
    "type":1,
    "slug":"",
    "entity":"employee"
},{
    "name":"8749258125",
    "type":4,
    "slug":"",
    "entity":"description"
},{
    "name":"9748697490",
    "type":4,
    "slug":"",
    "entity":"description"
}],
"links":[{
    "source":0,
    "target":1,
    "value":1,
    "distance":5
},{
    "source":0,
    "target":2,
    "value":1,
    "distance":5
},{
    "source":1,
    "target":3,
    "value":4,
    "distance":5
},{
    "source":1,
    "target":4,
    "value":4,
    "distance":5
}]
}
```

and this is the api i am using ..

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
     pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <style>

        /* CSS Document */
        .link2 {
            stroke: #000;
            stroke-width: 2px;  
            stroke-dasharray:3,3;
        }

        .link1 {
            stroke: #000;
            stroke-width: 2px;
        }

        .nodetext {
            pointer-events: none;
        }

        .node.type4 {
            fill: #800000;
        }

        .node.type1 {
            fill: #BF00426;                
        }

        .node.type3 {
            fill: #0000A0;
            size: 20px;
        }

        .node.type2 {
            fill: #008000;
            size: 40px;
        }
        .node.type4 {
            fill: #65000b;
            size: 40px;
        }


        image.circle {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .fadein {
            display: none;
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        .rectD {
            background-color: #000000;
            width: 70px;
            height: 30px
        }

        .rectL {
            background-color: #000000;
            width: 90px;
            height: 30px
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js?2.9.1"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>


        var w = 1200, h = 900, radius = d3.scale.log().domain([0,312000 ])
        .range([ "10", "50" ]);

        var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg").attr("width", w).attr(
        "height", h);

        vis.append("marker")
        .attr("id", "arrowhead")
        .attr("refX", 6 + 6) /*must be smarter way to calculate shift*/
        .attr("refY", 2)
        .attr("markerWidth", 6)
        .attr("markerHeight", 4)
        .attr("orient", "auto")
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", "M 0,0 V 4 L6,2 Z"); //this is actual shape for arrowhead


        d3.json("myjson.json", function(data,error) {
            var force = self.force = d3.layout.force().nodes(data.nodes).links(
            data.links).linkDistance(function(d) {
                return (d.distance * 10);
            })
            //.friction(0.5)
            .charge(-250).size([ w, h ]).start();

            var link = vis.selectAll("line.link").data(data.links).enter().append(
            "svg:line").attr("class", function(d) {
                return "link" + d.value + "";
            }).attr("x1", function(d) {
                return d.source.x;
            }).attr("y1", function(d) {
                return d.source.y;
            }).attr("x2", function(d) {
                return d.target.x;
            }).attr("y2", function(d) {
                return d.target.y;
            }).attr("marker-end", function(d) {
                if (d.value == 10 || d.value==1) {
                    return "url(#arrowhead)"
                } else {
                    return " "
                }
                ;
            });

            function openLink() {
                return function(d) {
                    var url = "";
                    if (d.slug != "") {
                        url = d.slug
                    } else if(d.type == 2) {
                        url = "clients/" + d.slug
                    } else if(d.type == 3) {
                        url = "agencies/" + d.slug
                    }
                    window.open("//" + url)
                }
            }

            var node = vis.selectAll("g.node").data(data.nodes).enter().append(
            "svg:g").attr("class", "node").call(force.drag);


            // size of the nodes are given here
            node.append("circle").attr("class", function(d) {
                return "node type" + d.type
            }).attr("r", function(d) {
                if (d.entity == "description") {
                    return 16
                } else if(d.entity=="company"){
                    return 14
                }else if(d.entity=="number"){
                    return 25
                }else{
                    return 18
                }
            })


            node.append("text").attr("class", function(d) {
                return "nodetext title_" + d.name
            }).attr("dx", 0).attr("dy", ".35em").style("font-size", "10px").attr(
            "text-anchor", "middle").style("fill", "white").text(
            function(d) {                
                return d.name                
            });

            node.on("mouseover", function(d) {
                if (d.entity == "description") {
                    d3.select(this).select('text').transition().duration(300).text(
                    function(d) {
                        return d.name;
                    }).style("font-size", "15px")

                } else if (d.entity == "employee") {
                    var asdf = d3.select(this);
                    asdf.select('text').remove();

                    asdf.append("text").text(function(d) {
                        return d.prefix + ' ' + d.fst_name
                    }).attr("class", "nodetext").attr("dx", 0).attr("dy", ".35em")
                    .style("font-size", "5px")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle").style("fill", "white")
                    .transition().duration(300).style("font-size", "12px");

                    asdf.append("text").text(function(d) {
                        return d.snd_name
                    }).attr("class", "nodetext").attr("transform",
                    "translate(0, 12)").attr("dx", 0).attr("dy", ".35em")
                    .style("font-size", "5px")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle").style("fill", "white")
                    .transition().duration(300).style("font-size", "12px");
                } else {
                    d3.select(this).select('text').transition().duration(300)
                    .style("font-size", "15px")
                }

                if (d.entity == "company") {
                    d3.select(this).select('image').attr("width", "100px").attr("x",
                    "-46px").attr("y", "-36.5px").attr("xlink:href",
                    function(d) {
                        return d.name
                    });
                }

                if (d.entity == "company") {

                    d3.select(this).select('circle').transition().duration(300)
                    .attr("r", 28)

                } else if (d.entity == "employee") {
                    d3.select(this).select('circle').transition().duration(300)
                    .attr("r", 15)
                }
            });

            node.on("mouseout", function(d) {
                if (d.entity == "company") {
                    d3.select(this).select('text').transition().duration(300).text(
                    function(d) {
                        return d.name;
                    }).style("font-size", "10px")
                } else if (d.entity == "employee") {
                    ///////////////////////////
                    // CHANGE
                    ///////////////////////////

                    d3.select(this).selectAll('text').remove();

                    //d3.select(this).select('text')
                    d3.select(this).append('text').text(function(d) {
                        return d.name;
                    }).style("font-size", "14px").attr("dx", 0).attr("dy", ".35em")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle").style("fill", "white")
                    .attr("class", "nodetext").transition().duration(300)
                    .style("font-size", "10px")

                } else {
                    d3.select(this).select('text').transition().duration(300)
                    .style("font-size", "10px")
                }

                if (d.entity == "company") {
                    d3.select(this).select('image').attr("width", "70px").attr("x",
                    "-36px").attr("y", "-36px").attr("xlink:href",
                    function(d) {
                        return d.img_hrefD
                    });
                }

                if (d.entity == "company" || d.entity == "employee") {

                    d3.select(this).select('circle').transition().duration(300)
                    .attr("r", 18)
                }

            });

            node.on("mouseover", fade(.4, "red")).on("mouseout", fade(1));

            var linkedByIndex = {};
            data.links.forEach(function(d) {
                linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
            });

            function isConnected(a, b) {
                return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index]
                    || linkedByIndex[b.index + "," + a.index]
                    || a.index == b.index;
            }

            force.on("tick", function() {
                link.attr("x1", function(d) {
                    return d.source.x;
                }).attr("y1", function(d) {
                    return d.source.y;
                }).attr("x2", function(d) {
                    return d.target.x;
                }).attr("y2", function(d) {
                    return d.target.y;
                });

                node.attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
                });
            });


            function getConnected(cn, d, level) {
                node.each(function(o) {
                    if(isConnected(d, o) && cn.indexOf(o) == -1) {
                        cn.push(o);
                        if(level > 0) getConnected(cn, o, level-1);
                    };
                });

                return cn;
            }


            function fade(opacity,color) {
                return function(d) {

                    node.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
                        thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
                        this.setAttribute('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
                        return thisOpacity;
                    });

                    link.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
                        return o.source === d || o.target === d ? 1 : opacity;
                    })

                    .style("stroke", function(o) {
                        return o.source === d || o.target === d ? color : "#000" ;
                    });
                };

            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

[image]  this is the picture coming which sometimes shows two nodes not connected.... But when i use the first json it beautifuly works

Comment: Could you elaborate on what's not working and how please? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: I am getting this error  [21:47:47.999] Expected color but found '#BF00426'.  Error in parsing value for 'fill'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost:7001/D3Application/churnLink.jsp:29
[21:47:48.810] Unknown property 'box-sizing'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost:7001/D3Application/churnLink.jsp
[21:47:48.853] Error in parsing value for 'marker-end'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost:7001/D3Application/churnLink.jsp

Comment: @LarsKotthoff the picture I added first is the result of the the first json I wrote ..and the second json I wrote is producing the second one.1st json  is lengthly but I see no difference between them can you help me here??

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with the second picture -- there are 5 nodes and 4 links in both your JSON and the generated graph.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff now see I am getting like this the edges are nt connected

Comment: Looks like it doesn't like the empty value for `marker-end`. Have you tried removing that?

Comment: I did not understand Lars the two jsons are alike write ??then why two will generate two different pattern??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that it appears to be not working is that the links in your second JSON have a value that doesn't occur in the other JSON. This means that they'll be assigned a different class for which no CSS has been defined. The links are there, they're just not styled so that you can see them.

Adding this CSS fixes it.

```
.link4 {
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vuCAx/).